# How to generate A1 poster with designated boxed content in LaTeX?

Tags: posters

I'm quite a novice with using LaTeX. I have only previously used to software to write simplistic reports. I now need to use LaTeX to make an A1 poster.
I've made an image in powerpoint as to how I'd like my poster to look. In each of the boxes I want content; and I want the content to remain within its designated box. 
[image: Image of how i'd like it to look]

I suppose, my question is, is this possible in LaTeX? And what would be the simplest way to do so?

Is there a way I can have this particular image as the background image for the whole document, then type content in its relevant block; with the blocks fixed to the size of the boxes in the background image? (Sort of overlayed ontop of the image.)
Or alternatively, can I frame each block; force some blocks to be coloured, give them a border and a background image?

So far I have a document with blocks, framed minitabs in each block. But this way causes big gaps between the frames of the minitabs in each block
[image: Image of my current latex doc]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does `1` in a  box mean that it is meant for all boxes numbered this way, i.e. the content is the same for all this boxes, etc.? Welcome to TeX.SE, by the way. I think `tcbrasters` from the `tcolorbox` package might be a method...

Comment: Hello Christian! No; I would actually like the numbers in the background. My project is on 'Transversals of Cayley Tables of Groups' so the image represents a transversal; I'd like to incorporate the background to represent the actual project

Comment: See my first attempt. I'll change the numbers accordingly

Answer (score 3):

Such a `grid` of boxes can be easily achieved with `tcbraster` from `tcolorbox`, a marvellous package.

Define a `tcbraster` environment with the relevant data (4 rows, 4 columns), set the height and an eventual spacing)

Define a special `\posterbox` command for the content, the numbers in the background can be achieved with an `underlay` and `TikZ` statement.

The coloured background boxes can be achieved with special styles, predefined.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[landscape,a1paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,x11names, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{bluebox/.style={colback=DarkSlateGray1},whitebox/.style={colback=white}}

\newtcbox[auto counter]{\posterbox}[2][]{%
  fontupper={\LARGE\bfseries},
  enhanced jigsaw,
  sharp corners,
  colframe={blue},
  nobeforeafter,
  underlay={\node[scale=10,opacity=0.3] (A) at (interior) {\huge #2}; },
  whitebox,
  #1,
}





\begin{document}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=4, raster equal height,raster column skip=2pt,raster height=\textheight, raster rows=4]
  \posterbox{1}{\blindtext} 
  \posterbox[bluebox]{2}{\blindtext} 
  \posterbox{3}{\blindtext} 
  \posterbox{4}{\blindtext} 
% 2nd row
  \posterbox{2}{\blindtext[2]} 
  \posterbox{3}{\blindtext} 
  \posterbox{4}{\blindtext} 
  \posterbox[bluebox]{1}{\blindtext} 
% 3rd row
  \posterbox{3}{\blindtext[3]} 
  \posterbox{4}{\blindtext} 
  \posterbox[bluebox]{1}{\blindtext} 
  \posterbox{2}{\blindtext} 
% 4th row
  \posterbox[bluebox]{4}{\blindtext} 
  \posterbox{3}{\blindtext} 
  \posterbox{2}{\blindtext} 
  \posterbox{1}{\blindtext} 
\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Original version

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[a0paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox[auto counter]{\posterbox}[1][]{%
  fontupper={\LARGE\bfseries},
  enhanced jigsaw,
  sharp corners,
  colback={white!90!yellow},
  colframe={blue},
  nobeforeafter,
  underlay={\node[scale=10,opacity=0.3] (A) at (interior) {\huge\thetcbcounter}; },
  #1
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=4, raster equal height,raster column skip=2pt,raster height=\textheight, raster rows=4]
  \posterbox{\blindtext} 
  \posterbox{\blindtext} 
  \posterbox{\blindtext} 
  \posterbox{\blindtext} 
% 2nd row
  \posterbox[colback=yellow]{\blindtext[2]} 
  \posterbox{\blindtext} 
  \posterbox{\blindtext} 
  \posterbox{\blindtext} 
% 3rd row
  \posterbox{\blindtext[3]} 
  \posterbox{\blindtext} 
  \posterbox{\blindtext} 
  \posterbox{\blindtext} 
% 4th row
  \posterbox{\blindtext} 
  \posterbox{\blindtext} 
  \posterbox{\blindtext} 
  \posterbox{\blindtext} 
\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is excellent, thankyou! However, when trying to put this into Latex; the error shellesc.sty is not found. I've found a copy of this in a package named 'Tools' from Ctan; but after unzipping and running the tex document; the error is still occuring. Is there somewhere I need to copy and paste the package to get my Latex to run it? Furthermore, I'm using Texmaker, whereas the package for shellesc opens in Texworks

Comment: @Lauren: You have to update your TeX distribution then. Installing single packages somewhere is not the best way