# How can I create numbered flashcards?

Tags: numbering, flashcards

I'm using the "flashcards" document class and I want to implement an automatic numbering in the front part, such that, for example, when I write:

```
\documentclass[avery5388,grid,frame]{flashcards}
\cardfrontstyle[\large\slshape]{headings}

\begin{document}
\begin{flashcard}[Definition]{Something}
   Text
\end{flashcard}
\end{document}
```

it gets rendered to "Definition (i)", where "i" is the flashcard's number in the document.
For now I tried to create a custom counter, and manually writing the code to show it inside the `[Definition]` part of the flashcard's command, but it is unpractical in the long run.
Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post a compilable document, not such fragments only. The `flashcard` class is a little bit aged, dating back to 2000 and scarce updates.

Comment: Edited with a compilable example. Is there a newer class for the same purpose? I have not the knowledge to create one myself.

Comment: I know of no newer class, but that doesn't mean there is one nevertheless. I'll suggest the very powerful `tcolorbox` package with its `tcbraster` library, however

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/346618/31729

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way with `tcolorbox` and its `tcbraster` environment, there is no direct connection to printer labels producers like `Avery` etc, the specification has to be done manually.

The `auto counter` provides a new counter, here named 'flashcard' (well, hidden in a complex internal name) and `\thetcbcounter` is a wrapper for `\the...` macro connected to the counter.

I chose some of the most frequently used `tcolorbox` options which are pretty easy to remember and are very clear in their meanings (in my opinion)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

%[avery5388,grid,frame]{flashcards}
%\cardfrontstyle[\large\slshape]{headings}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{flashcard}[1][]{enhanced,
 title={Definition \thetcbcounter},
 sharp corners,
 boxrule=0.5pt,
 height=5cm,
 coltitle=black,
 colback=white, 
 colbacktitle=yellow,
 #1}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=4,raster equal height]
\begin{flashcard}
   Text
\end{flashcard}
\begin{flashcard}
\end{flashcard}
\begin{flashcard}
\end{flashcard}
\begin{flashcard}
\end{flashcard}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

[image]